# CVcapture From 2 WebCams

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, video-capture

I am taking input from the camera. to be more clear i added a photo:
2 cameras that connected on the same usb port
[image]

with `OpenCV` as the following :

```
#define CamLeft 2
#define CamRight 0
#define WIN_L "win_l"
#define WIN_R "win_r"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   VideoCapture capLeft(CamLeft);
   bool opened = capLeft.isOpened();
   if(!opened /*|| !capRight.isOpened()*/)  // check if we succeeded
      return -1;

   Mat edges;
   namedWindow(WIN_L,1);
   for(;;)
   {
       Mat frameL;
       Mat frameR;
       capLeft >> frameL; // get a new frame from camera
       cvtColor(frameL, edges, CV_RGB2RGBA);
       imshow(WIN_L, edges);
         if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

So I am creating a window named "win_l" stands for window left and process video capture. It works well. Now I upgraded my code to support another camera like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    VideoCapture capLeft(CamLeft);
    VideoCapture capRight(CamRight);
    bool opened = capLeft.isOpened();
    if(!opened /*|| !capRight.isOpened()*/)  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    namedWindow(WIN_L,1);
    namedWindow(WIN_R,1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frameL;
        Mat frameR;
        capLeft >> frameL; // get a new frame from camera
        cvtColor(frameL, edges, CV_RGB2RGBA);
        imshow(WIN_L, edges);
        imshow(WIN_R, edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But then I don't see the debugger hit this line: `bool opened....` is it the correct way to take capture from 2 cameras?

Comment: Yes it is correct way to open second camera. Why would you expect debugger to put that line?

Comment: try to compile this code and you will see that code is not passing this line :     VideoCapture capRight(CamRight);

Comment: I don't think you are telling your problem clearly... Do you have an unexpected behavior in runtime? Do you have en error in runtime? Do you have an error in compiling phase?

Comment: no the program start ok but i got something that looks like thread lock. the program dont execute after this line VideoCapture capRight(CamRight);

Comment: Does commenting out the capleft line allow capright to proceed? Have you tried doing the open and capture for camleft and then close it, followed by open + capture for camright?  I suspect you can't capture from both cameras at the same time or have both open at the same time as they are on the same usb cable or something odd like that.

Comment: commenting one of the cameras makes it work. i knew that, i need to split it into 2 usb ports i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect USB bandwidth allocating problem. Not very sure if that is the cause though, but it is usually the case for 2 separate camera with individual USB cable each.

But still, do give it a shot. Some methods to overcome that problem: 1)put a Sleep(ms) in between the lines of your capture line. 2)Use lower resolution which would reduce the bandwidth used by each camera. 3)Use MJPEG format(compressed frames).

> EDIT:

I came across this website, [WEBCAM AND USB DRIVERS](http://www.zonetrigger.com/articles/troubleshooting_webcams/), thought you might like to read it.

Anyway, I am not sure if both cameras are able to run concurrently with each other only through one USB port and the reason is as mentioned(I actually forgotten about it. My bad):

USB: Universal Serial Bus, as the name suggest, it is a serial data transmission, meaning, that it can only send data from one device to/and from the computer.

What happening in your code is a deadlock, causing your program to not progress, even on one camera.

2 reasons that causes this:

1)I suspect that the driver for each camera is consistently overwriting each other, sending an I/O Request Packet (IRP), and the "pipe" keeps on receiving and processing each request, and the system keep deallocating each resource immediately after it is allocated. This goes on and on.

2)There is starvation from the 2nd camera, where if it is not allocated the resource, the program cannot progress. Hence the system is stuck in a loop where the 2nd camera keep requesting for the resource.

However, it would be weird if somebody invented this 2 webcam using a single serial bus when each camera needs a channel/pipe of it's own to communicate with the system. Maybe you would like to check with the manufacturer straight? Maybe they came up with a workaround, hence they invented this camera?

If not, the only purpose for this invention is pretty redundant. I can only think of a security purpose, one configured for night view and one configured for day view.

Comment: does not work either... also tried on different machines and usb ports

Comment: Have you tested if both camera works on it's own? In addition, OpenCV reads in `BGR`as a default and not `RGB`. You might want to consider changing this line: `cvtColor(frameL, edges, CV_RGB2RGBA);`

Comment: Please view my edit. I doubt that it can work concurrently through one USB driver.